# Microsoft Visio wrong rectangle size with text in it

Tags: image, visio

I create black rectangle in Microsoft Visio. I put some white text in it. Small text in the center. Save it as image. Open image - great, black image is exact size of rectangle with small white text in it.

Now I increase the size of internal text to fill almost whole rectangle. I save as image. Oops, image appears with white borders around it, while I need the same black box with just big text in it.

It seems Visio thinks of some margins or padding or whatever for the text. I can not find any setting for the rectangle to override it so that I have just black box of defined size with big text in it.

Is there any solution? Thank you.

**Edit:** Curtiss, I do not touch "shapes" at all. The only element I use is rectangle. Open Visio (I have 2010). New -> Create. Select "Rectangle". Draw rectangle with border (to see its boundaries). Double click on it. Put any text inside. Increase text's font so that text occupy whole rectangle (alternatively - reshape rectangle so that text fits it). Then deselect everything (to save whole drawing). File -> Save as -> jpg/gif/tif. Save it and open in any graphical editor.

(if I would be able to attach pictures to questions...)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the image while you are editing the master shape?
Can you provide more details on the question?

By the way, you can edit the properties by right-click on the text and select "Paragraph..."

Comment: Curtiss, thank you. See edit of the question please.

Comment: I am using Visio 2003, even though I create a black rectangle with small text inside it, the margin area is still around the rectangle. (Because I set the background color other than black)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct, in that Visio adds around the text, creating a larger textbox, which creates the larger overall image with the border.

You may look at the Paragraph settings to see if there are margins and spacing adjustments to make, to eliminate the overflow.

What I did, in a similar situation, was to create a separate textbox, instead of using the shape's textbox.  I then sized the font I wanted in the new textbox, CTRL+C to copy the textbox, then Paste Special, as a picture.  With the new image of the text, I cropped to fit, then selected all and saved as JPEG.